# Is base64 encoded file smaller than straight hexdump?

Tags: base64, hexdump

I was wondering if base64 provides any compression compared to straight hex-dump - that means turning every byte into two characters from range [a-f0-9].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it does, because base64 has more characters to work with—64 instead of the 16 of hexdump. This is one of the purposes of base64.

[The Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) shows you the gain: If the binary data is `n` bytes, the base64 data is `4*ceil(n/3)` bytes. (Compared to `2*n` bytes for the hexdump.)

So, instead of a 100% overhead, you get roughly a 33% overhead.

Comment: I don't actually know for what purpose did I ask this question 7 months ago. But the more you know...